# Change SQL Server Report Viewer Control color properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I'm using asp.net and report viewer control in a web page. I want to format its colors to match the page.

What properties do I need to set to change the backcolor or other style properties of the below image only(it appears inside the report viewer control)?  Can I change them from the reportviewer control or do I need to edit the markup of the .RDL file?  If these properties can be changed in the RDL file where should I look to change them?

Please, I only want to know if I can change the colors/properties of what I show in the image below. Thanks
[image: Toolbar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at the styles used by the control when it's rendered on the page and override them on your own CSS file. Just make sure you reference your css file on the page containing the report viewer control.

Worst case scenario, you can apply your own styles using jQuery. All you need to know is the ids or classes (or whatever selector is appropriate) of the html elements when the control is rendered.

The bottom line is that you can accomplish this because the report viewer control is not some sort of ActiveX control or Applet of any sort. The only thing on this control that actually uses an ActiveX control is the "print" icon, which, if I recall correctly, can send the output directly to the default printer w/o asking you to select one when used within Internet Explorer. On other browsers, doesn't even render the print icon.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The ReportViewer control does inline styling so that could be a problem with attempting to use CSS. Got any suggestions as to how to make jQuery work, or specific examples you have encountered? Thanks

Comment: @Encryption: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457740/how-to-modify-style-attribute-of-element-with-known-id-using-jquery