# How refresh the style of an HTML element after changing it using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML page containing XML.     Using Javascript, the XML attributes can be changed when the user clicks a button.    (So far, everything works)

However, the attribute that is changed is used in the linked CSS to determine the background color of the element.    When the attribute value is changed, the style is not refreshed, so the color doesn't change.

I can alter the javascript to also change the color, but that would involve hardcoding the color, and partially defeat the point of using CSS.

So, it seems to me, I need to do one of two things, and I can't figure out how to do either:

- read the color from the CSS, and then assign it using javascript
- somehow use javascript to have the CSS re-applied to the document.

Which approach is better?       I assume the 2nd is easier, unless there is a side-effect I haven't thought of.      And, whichever approach is better, HOW TO DO IT?

My CSS contains:

```
*[cleared=true] {
background:lightgrey;
}
```

My XML looks like this:

```
<Transfer ID="31266" Date="2015-04-14" Cleared="false">
    <AccountCharge Account="Unplus">-826.20</AccountCharge>
    <AccountCharge Account="Amex">826.20</AccountCharge>
    <TransactionID>1504140662984782</TransactionID>
</Transfer>
```

My Javascript is:

```
function Reconcile(Element_ID){
try {
    var c=document.getElementById(Element_ID);
    c.setAttribute('Cleared','True');
    }
catch(e) {
    alert(e.description);
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the script from modifying 'Cleared' to 'Date', and I can see the date change.       The 'Cleared' attribute is not displayed directly by the CSS, but is used to set the formatting of other elements and/or attributes.

Changing the value of 'Cleared' before the page is loaded has the effect I expect - the CSS causes the formatting I expect.      However, after the page is loaded, when the javascript changes the value of 'Cleared', no visible change in formatting takes place.

Comment: could you share some code here, what attribute are you using and how are you changing it.

Comment: Are you certain that the attribute value is definitely being updated? As Franky said, please supply your code.

Comment: Could it be that the issue is with XML and case sensitivity (and the lower case selector in the CSS)?

Comment: I checked on the case-sensitivity (hadn't noticed that 'Cleared' was written 'cleared' in the CSS), but that did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to assign classes?

Either with pure Javascript:

`document.getElementById('selector').className = 'active';`

or with jQuery:

`jQuery('#selector').addClass('active')`;

This way you can use CSS classes and not hardcode the colour in your Javascript code.

---

See implementation of addClass and removeClass in Javascript:
http://jaketrent.com/post/addremove-classes-raw-javascript/

Comment: I now have it working.     Turned out to be a few different problems.        I was not using class names in my CSS, so didn't initially see how to apply this idea.       Also, my XML was contained inside a <TD> element, but it was the XML that had the ID attribute, and it was the TD element that needed to be altered by the CSS.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score -2):

There's some info about changing style of HTML element with jQuery: [jQuery changing style of HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086201/jquery-changing-style-of-html-element)

There's some more if you change your mind: [How to modify STYLE attribute of element with known ID using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457740/how-to-modify-style-attribute-of-element-with-known-id-using-jquery)

You can either add some extra styles or just switch the target class/id.

Comment: The original question says nothing about jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is javascript library, it's like using existing stuff to achieve desired effect faster, sorry for the confusion

Comment: I know what jQuery is, I was simply pointing out that there's no mention of it in the question.

Comment: Well I would just go with javascript (jQuery) approach and get elements changed with it. My answer kinda implied it.

Comment: jQuery is something I should add to the list of things to learn when I have time, but for now, since I am unfamiliar with it, I don't think I want to go that route if I can avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.        Unfortunately, still haven't got it working.          What I am changing is an attribute of XML enclosed in HTML, not a native HTML element.        Does that matter?     CSS is fine with handling the formatting of the XML content, so I assume it isn't why the change in formatting isn't implemented automatically when the XML attribute changes.

Comment: I think I know what may be the problem.      I have multiple elements that all have the 'Cleared' attribute, and if any have 'Cleared=True', their display format should be altered.     In my CSS, I use